# Testing adding an item to my cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm learning rails and rspec and I've written a application that has a simple cart system. In order to test it I've written a request spec, however I've run into an error I don't quite understand, my spec is:

```
  context 'add item to cart' do
    Given!(:product){FactoryGirl.create(:product)}
    Given {get "/"}
    When {xhr get "/line_items?product_id=#{product.id}"}
    Then { response.body.include? 'class="item_price"' }
  end
```

and the error given is:

```
 Failure/Error: When {xhr get "/line_items?product_id=#{product.id}"}

     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2+)
```

I'm very new to this so I'm not sure what I should be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being:

```
  context "add item to cart" do
    Given!(:product){FactoryGirl.create(:product)}
    Given {get "/"}
    When {xhr :post, "/line_items?product_id=#{product.id}"}
    Then { response.body.include? "item_price" }
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

xhr is expecting more parameters : `xhr "get", "/line_items?product_id=#{product.id}"`
Try this:

```
  context 'add item to cart' do
    Given!(:product){FactoryGirl.create(:product)}
    Given {get "/"}
    When {xhr "get", "/line_items?product_id=#{product.id}"}
    Then { response.body.include? 'class="item_price"' }
  end
```